# Unmarshal JSON to String, BigInteger and BigDecimal with jackson very close

Tags: jackson

We are using jackson, and I see this in the code

```
DeserializationConfig.Feature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS
DeserializationConfig.Feature.USE_BIG_INTEGER_FOR_INTS
```

But how do I get jackson to use those features now?

This would be the perfect situation. I just want a Map result with String, BigDecimal and BigIntegers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Enable the feature on the ObjectMapper.](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html#configure%28org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature,%20boolean%29)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationConfig.Feature.…);
```

[Update for version >= 2.0.0:](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#enable%28com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature%29)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS);
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_INTEGER_FOR_INTS);
```

Comment: As for Javadocs link provided there is no Feature class in DeserializationConfig. I use: mapper.enable( DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS );

Comment: @JoséAndias: Thanks for pointing that out. [DeserializationConfig.Feature](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/DeserializationConfig.Feature.html) got obviously purged with Version 2.0.x.

Comment: @JoséAndias: Since your edit was rejected I included your solution in my edit.

Comment: Thanks @nutlike. I guess I was not making the answer a better one... I see the vote match result of 3:2 and the 3x reason: "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post." Makes one think about the edit/voting system. Unfortunately I see no positive conclusion would come out for the community, was not your attention on the matter to correct this "democratic" malfunction.